# How can I crop my pages in LaTeX to fit the content such that every page might be a different size?

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am typesetting notes on a daily basis in LaTeX (Overleaf, at the moment). Each day's notes are of a different length, of course. I would like the rendered .pdf to scale the length of each page to the length of the day's notes. (For instance, each page will be 8.5" wide but the length might range from 1" to 30".)

This may not be well-advised, I just think it might be neat because it will avoid ugly whitespace under a small page of notes.

I see that there are ways of procedurally determining each page's dimensions but the options I've found only allow setting page size *before* content is set. Given that I don't know the length of the notes before I've written them, I'd like this ``cropping'' step to come after the content. Is this totally naive and contrary to the fundamental structure of LaTeX compilation?

I know (from another Stack Overflow post) that the console utility ``pdfcrop'' exists---I just wanted a solution I could deploy natively in Overleaf if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `pdfcrop` in Overleaf. If you create a second file e.g. `crop.tex` with these contents:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{shellesc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcommand\mainfile{main}

\begin{document}

\ShellEscape{latexmk \mainfile}
\ShellEscape{pdfcrop \mainfile}

\includepdf[pages=-]{\mainfile-crop.pdf}

\end{document}
```

If you compile with `crop.tex` open on the left, you should get the cropped version. (If your main file isn't `main.tex` you gotta change the definition of `\mainfile` accordingly.)